# Alignment error in table / tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

The following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{House Lannister} &
    Cersei \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Jaime \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Tyrion \\  
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

results in the following error

```
l.15 \end{tabularx}
                   
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

It looks as intended:
[image: Example output]
(I am aware I should have used `multirow` but that did not work at all.)

What is wrong in the code above?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You've defined the `tabularx` environment to have 2 columns, but then you also write `\multicolumn{3}{...}{...}`. Did you maybe mean to write `\multicolumn{2}{...}{...}`?

Comment: How exactly do you want your table to look? Further to Mico's issue, I added ``\\`` after `{House Lannister}` and moved the `&` to before `Cersai`, it compiles the code but the table [looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/hriJd6r), is this what you want your table to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example finally worked. But, honestly, I did not comprehend quite, what was the final straw.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{House Lannister} &
    Cersei \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Jaime \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Tyrion \\  
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You used `\multicolumn` in your question. As the name says, it spans over many columns. Instead, you want something over many rows, so `\multirow` is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems with `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, I suggest using `tabularray` package. It is simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={XX}, hlines, vlines}
   \SetCell[r=3]{l} House Lannister &
    Cersei \\ 
    & Jaime \\ 
    & Tyrion \\  
\end{tblr}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]